# Intended purpose of Self-Learner badge on SE?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, badges, stack-exchange, self-answer

Is it encouraged to post unasked questions we know the answer to if they seem useful?

Or is this only intended to be used when a question goes long enough that the postee eventually learned the answer?

Comment: I think it's the latter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing that says you can't answer your own questions if you know the answer. The [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) explicitly says you can:

> It’s also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you’re on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question.

So one might say that's encouraged, especially where it adds value. And after all, that does benefit other people

> Or is this only intended to be used when a question goes long enough that the postee eventually learned the answer?

Having answered Q1 the answer to this is no. I'd say it's explicitly intended to encourage people to contribute stuff they think needs answering. However, it does have the side effect of rewarding people who answer their own question.

Answer (score 4):

If you post a question on SO you might still find the answer yourself later on. "Self-Learner" encourages you to post this answer on SO, instead of just moving on and leaving the SO question unanswered.

Other people that come to SO later and have the same question will benefit from this answer.

Answer (score 2):

After this question was asked a blog post on the subject was published:

> <sub>July 1st 2011</sub>
>
> [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)
>
> (...)
>
> Bottom line — **never hesitate to ask and answer your own question on any Stack Exchange site.** Please do! It’s all part of our shared mission to make the internet better.